# Game controller connected through USB changes its VID/PID and driver

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager, game-controller

I have an unusual problem with my stick and thought maybe some might have also encountered it. I know it's not a 'big boy' stick, but still. :)

So when I first plug the stick in everything works properly, A is A, B is B, guide button works.

Then after some time (cannot identify under what circumstances this happens, it seems reboot-proof) the stick basically is recognised as a different one, buttons are swapped and guide button stops working.

I have further investigated this and found that:

1. In windows game controllers list initially the stick is recognized as **"Controller (HORI mini fighting stick)"**, when it stops working it becomes just **"HORI mini fighting stick"**.
2. In device manager the VID and PID belong to HORI and proper device, but when it stops working properly they change to something else (some random, generic vendor with unknown PID).
3. When the stick changes its behaviour it also loses 'Xbox 360 Controller' driver.
4. Steam recognises these 2 'drivers' (it's not really a driver, it's detected as a different device) as seperate devices.
5. Unplugging the stick and plugging it back in works for the front USB panel, but when I do that for the back panel, once the stick has been recognised as the 'imposter' stick, it will stay that way no matter how many times I plug it in.
6. I am unaware of any button combinations that would let's say switch the controller from XINPUT to DINPUT and possibly cause any change to how it's recognised.

While I can work around it (temporarily, untill it randomly stops working again), I would like to plug the controller into the back panel, but right now the buttons are reversed, and some of them simply don't work.

Can anyone help? If this is not the place or you think there's a better place to ask for help, please let me know and I would appreciate if you could guide me to where I could get help with this issue.

Thanks a lot.